# Importing timezone from django.utils for Django tutorial 2 does not define 'timezone' in command console results

Tags: django, django-models

I am in the tutorial for Django 1.8 and I am on this page
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/
-about halfway through the page

I have followed all the steps up to this point, but when I get to calling
q.was_published_recently
in the command console it returns "timezone not defined"

here's the result

```
11         return self.question_text

12     def was_published_recently(self):

13         return self.pub_date >= timezone.now()     -datetime.timedelta(days=1)

14

15


NameError: name 'timezone' is not defined
```

-And here is my code in my text editor

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

import datetime 



class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)




class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

if anybody has any insight into why my custom method isn't working to recall the question originally posted on my django project please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the django package id present in the same Python version.

You can check this my running python interpreter in your system, them try to run:

```
from django.utils import timezone

print(timezone.now())
```

If this works for you try importing the same statement in this way:

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= tz.now() - tdelta(days=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py I added my time zone and then I run codes
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC-06:00' (my pc current time zone)

code:

```
from django.utils import timezone
print(timezone.now())
```

Now it's working fine. I know it's an old post but still, it may help someone, who is new like me.

Thanks, kt14

Comment: Consider writing Python code `between backticks` to format it nicely.